# Outputting foreach loop in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to simply get a list of computers and their OU's from a CSV file of computer names

```
Add-PSSnapin quest.activeroles.admanagement

$results = @()
$computers = Get-Content "computers.csv"

foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
    $results += Get-QADComputer $computer | select name, parentcontainer
}

$results = Export-CSV -path "computerswithous.csv"
```

But it errors out asking me to supply values.  How can I simply output this data to a CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not include it in the post but is this what you were getting:

```
cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject:
```

Simple answer is this line

```
$results = Export-CSV -path "computerswithous.csv"
```

Should most likely be this

```
$results | Export-CSV -path "computerswithous.csv"
```

In your example `Export-CSV` has no input data which is what your prompt (not error) is requesting. You actually want to pipe the `$results` to the CSV file.

You also could do away with that construct as well and just use standard pipeline to get what you are looking for.

```
Add-PSSnapin quest.activeroles.admanagement

Get-Content "computers.csv" | ForEach-Object{Get-QADComputer $_} | 
    Select Name,ParentContainer | Export-CSV -Path "computerswithous.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed something so simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that intermediate collection (`$results`) at all. Just wrap the `foreach` loop in a `sub-expression`, and send it on to the pipeline.

```
Add-PSSnapin quest.activeroles.admanagement

$computers = Get-Content "computers.csv"

$(foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
  Get-QADComputer $computer | select name, parentcontainer
}) | Export-CSV -path "computerswithous.csv"
```